# How to config OpenJPA encoding?

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8, openjpa

I'm having an issue with OpenJPA. I used it to persist values in MySQL DB. Amoung these values, there's a String value that has a spanish character (á). The data was persisted correctly, with the special character being shown perfectly in the DB.

The problem comes when, within my Java program, I try to query the DB with one of the parameters having this special character. Here's an example:

```
    private static final String getPerdiodoEstadoAfiliacionParaOS = 
        "SELECT x FROM PeriodoAfiliacion x WHERE " +
            "x.obraSocial=?1 " +
            "AND x.tipoPeriodoAfiliacion LIKE ?2";

    public static List<PeriodoAfiliacion> getPerdiodoEstadoAfiliacionParaOS(EntityManager em, ObraSocial os, String periodoABuscar) {
        if(os==null) return new ArrayList<PeriodoAfiliacion>();

        Query query = em.createQuery(getPerdiodoEstadoAfiliacionParaOS);
        query.setParameter(1, os);
        query.setParameter(2, periodoABuscar);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

So, parameter number 2 (the one shown as ?2), it's a string with a special character in it.
The query comes back empty when there's actually data.

I know the problem is the special character, because if I pass as a parameter another String that doesn't have the special character in it, the query comes back with results as expected.

So, I don't know what the problem is really. I guess it has something to do with the way the parameter is passed from OpenJPA to the DB engine.

Do you guys have suggestions??

Comment: Can you post your persistence.xml. Are you usind MySql?

Comment: Hi! Sorry I did not answer. I never received notification of your comment. Nevermind, I gave up and took all special characters out :)